# GitHub pages only displays html, from website repository that has CSS folders

Tags: css, git, twitter-bootstrap, github

As a part of a web development course I am following I customized some of the materials to make my own website, and then pushed the repository to github.

However, When I go to its respective github page it only displays the html, despite the fact that I have used bootstrap and CSS in its creation, and can visualize the intended complete website display using browsersync.

Can someone help me identify what I am doing wrong?

This is my website: https://andreiadomz.github.io/omeusitenogit/index.html
and below the corresponding repository: https://github.com/Andreiadomz/omeusitenogit

Comment: `css` != `CSS`.

Comment: sorry that is a bit cryptic for me

Comment: See: https://github.com/github/linguist#using-gitattributes

Comment: There are a few issues with this, do you use any framework on building your page? If not, you can manually copy and push the required dependencies (css, js) to the repository. In your `index.html`, refer to the dependencies instead of `node_modules`

Comment: Hi there, I use bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0):

Visiting the provided link for your website and opening the developer tools (<kbd>ctrl+shift+i</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl+alt+i</kbd>) allows you to see that there is an issue with the way that many of your CSS and javascript files are being referenced in your HTML.
The first being that you're referencing files in a folder named 'css', yet the folder in your repository is 'CSS', which is not equivalent.
Though many of the issues you're experiencing involve pretty fundamental concepts of creating a website, so rather than attempting to provide a list of solutions to each of these issues, my best advice would be to use this as an opportunity to become familiar with your browsers developer tools.

***Note:*** I'd also recommend adding '*.DS_Store*', '*_MACOSX*', and '*npm-debug.log*' to your .gitignore file as the first two files are additional files created by OSX and the third is created to troubleshoot issues with your package.json, as they aren't necessary to create your website.

Answer (score 0):

It's case sensitive change css to CSS in your index.html OR change your CSS dir to css

Comment: changing css to CSS in my index worked partially - now I am able to see some color on navbar, header, and footer, but bootstrap definitely not yet working, as you can see from rechecking the same website link now. The other option to change CSS dir to css didn't work.

Comment: You use nodejs for local development right ? I find this css path is not valid for release on github https://andreiadomz.github.io/omeusitenogit/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/CSS/bootstrap.min.css as your repo does not has node_modules directory. check it and put the bootstrap.min.css into css/CSS directory and remember change your index.html related path, you'll get it. :)